# SQL query using Sum() and count() functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum, pivot

I'm trying to query in PostgresQL using the SUM function to get the total of 3 different row types (Root, Dynamic, Test). I used the Sum() function for the first attempt and the Count() function for the second attempt; both didn't work sadly. I expect a syntax error (since I'm a beginner at using SQL), but I'm not sure what it is and how to fix it!

1st attempt with the Sum() function:

```
SELECT 
sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'ROOT') as total_root_exercises, 
sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'DYNAMIC') as total_dynamic_exercises,
sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'TEST') as total_test_exercises
FROM exer 
GROUP BY "exerciseType"
```

2nd attempt with the Count() function:

```
select 
count(*) as total_root_exercises
where "exerciseType" = 'ROOT',
count(*) as total_Dynamic_exercises
where "exerciseType" in('DYNAMIC'),
count(*) as total_test_exercises
where "exerciseType" in('TEST')
FROM exer
```

Can I please get help with this? Thank you :)

Comment: usually case when goes with a then [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html). The answers provided are alternatives to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `filter` syntax to aggreagate functions, which is standard SQL and that Postgres supports:

```
select 
    count(*) filter(where "exerciseType" = 'ROOT'   ) as total_root_exercises,
    count(*) filter(where "exerciseType" = 'DYNAMIC') as total_Dynamic_exercises,
    count(*) filter(where "exerciseType" = 'TEST'   ) as total_test_exercises 
FROM exer
```

If you were to write this without the `filter` syntax (as in your first attempt), a portable syntax is:

```
select 
    sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'ROOT'    then 1 else 0 end) as total_root_exercises,
    sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'DYNAMIC' then 1 else 0 end) as total_Dynamic_exercises,
    sum(case when "exerciseType" = 'TEST'    then 1 else 0 end) as total_test_exercises 
FROM exer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT count(*) filter (where "exerciseType" = 'ROOT') as total_root_exercises, 
       count(*) filter (where "exerciseType" = 'DYNAMIC') as total_dynamic_exercises,
       count(*) filter (where "exerciseType" = 'TEST') as total_test_exercises
FROM exer ;
```

You don't need the outer aggregation, although you could return the results in rows rather than columns more simply:

```
select "exerciseType", count(*)
from exer
group by "exerciseType";
```

Note:  I strongly discourage the use of escaped column names.  Do not use double quotes when defining tables and don't use them in your queries.

Comment: Using double quotation marks for column names is the only thing that works, that's the case in Postgres at least. When call a column name that has all lower letters, it works without quotation marks, but when the column name has at least one capitalized letter, like in the case of "exerciseType" I must use the quotation marks. Or how else can I do it?

Comment: @user6688 . . . That is because the table was *defined* with double quotes.  Don't do that!  If someone else made that mistake, you are stick with it.  You do realize that this was the first answer.